# Game Engine - Change an image based on property?

Tags: texturing, game-engine, properties

For a HUD I'm making I would like the ammo to be displayed based on an image instead of text. How do I link what image is being displayed on a plane (a texture) based on a property?

Comment: You could also try a png sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. I made multiple planes and assigned different textures to each, then changed the visibility of each plane based on the property.